# SimpleCursorAdapter не заполняет ListView

Tags: android, listview, sqlite, база-данных

Здравствуйте!

Есть БД SQLITE, в которой две несвязанные таблицы. Данными из одной таблицы один ListView заполняется, и все работает хорошо. Сделано так:

> `String[] from =new String[]{h_db.COLUMN_ID,h_db.COLUMN_NAME,h_db.COLUMN_POINTS}; 
> int[] to = new int[]{R.id.h_item_tv1,R.id.h_item_tv2, R.id.h_item_tv3}; 
> scAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,R.layout.h_item, null, from, to, 0); 
> h_lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.h_listView); 
> h_lv.setAdapter(scAdapter); 
> this.getLoaderManager().initLoader(0,null, this);`

...

```
@Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int i, Bundle bundle) {
        return new MyCursorLoader(this, db);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> cursorLoader, Cursor cursor) {
        scAdapter.swapCursor(cursor);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> cursorLoader) {

    }
    static class MyCursorLoader extends CursorLoader {

        h_db db;

        public MyCursorLoader(Context context, h_db db) {
            super(context);
            this.db = db;
        }

        @Override
        public Cursor loadInBackground() {
            Cursor cursor = db.getAllData();
            return cursor;
        }

    }`
```

В другом активити заполняем другой ListView таким же способом. Из лога видно, что Adapter получает из БД все, что ему нужно(нет ошибок, что не существует чего-то в БД). При этом он не заполняет ListView.

```
    String[] from = new String[]{h_db.COLUMN_ACHIEV_ACH, h_db.COLUMN_COUNT_ACH, h_db.COLUMN_COST_ACH};
    int[] to = new int[]{R.id.a_item_ach, R.id.a_item_count, R.id.a_item_cost};
    scAdapter1 = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.a_item, null, from, to, 0);
    a_lv.setAdapter(scAdapter1);
    this.getLoaderManager().initLoader(0,null, this);
```

...

```
@Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int i, Bundle bundle) {
        return new MyCursorLoader(this, db);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> cursorLoader, Cursor cursor) {
        scAdapter1.swapCursor(cursor);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> cursorLoader) {

    }
    static class MyCursorLoader extends CursorLoader {

        h_db db;

        public MyCursorLoader(Context context, h_db db) {
            super(context);
            this.db = db;
        }

       @Override
        public Cursor loadInBackground() {
            Cursor cursor = db.getAllDataAch();
            return cursor;

        }
```

Собственно, курсоры с нужной инфой из БД получаю так:

```
  public Cursor getAllData() {
    return mDB.query(DB_TABLE, null, null, null, null, null, null);
}
public Cursor getAllDataAch() {
    return mDB.query(DB_TABLE_ACH, null, null, null, null, null, null);
}
```

В OnCreate для БД, следующий код:

```
 db.execSQL(DB_CREATE);
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        for (int i = 1; i < 25; i++) {
            cv.put(COLUMN_NAME, "yoba" + i);
            cv.put(COLUMN_POINTS, 2213-(2*i));
            db.insert(DB_TABLE, null, cv);
        }
        db.execSQL(DB_CREATE_ACH);
        ContentValues cv1 = new ContentValues();
        for (int i = 0; i == achs.length; i++) {
            cv1.put(COLUMN_ACHIEV_ACH, achs[i]);
            cv1.put(COLUMN_COUNT_ACH, 0);
            cv1.put(COLUMN_COST_ACH, cost[i]);
            db.insert(DB_TABLE_ACH,null,cv1);
        }
```

Как быть, почему не заполняется второй ListView?

Comment: Во втором попробуй id столбца указать. И что за дурацкое имя класса h_db

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблему решил: при создании второй таблицы в цикле нужно было поставить условие `i < achs.length;`. Иными словами, все работало правильно, просто у меня была пустая таблица.